# Ionic/Angular - Update label names with a link to change the picture

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am very new to Ionic/Angular and I am having a very hard time changing the label from 0 1 2 to something else like Profile Group Friend. I was able to get to this point with the help of google and youtube but I have spent few days trying to figure it out on changing the label and I am unable to find out a way to change it. I would really appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

code in HTML file

```
<ion-header [translucent]="false">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="search"> </ion-icon>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" ios="ellipsis-horizontal" md="ellipsis-vertical"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Pics</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <button *ngFor="let imageButton of imageButtons; let i = index" (click)="onClick(imageButton)"
    class="button">{{i}}</button>
  <img src="{{myimage || '/assets/test1.png'}}" (click)="addEvent();" />
  <h1>78%</h1>
</ion-content>
```

Code in ts file

```
export class IndividualstockPage implements OnInit {
imageSrc = '';
  messageText = '';
  imageButtons = [ {src:'/assets/Profile.png' } , 
  {src:'/assets/Group.png'}, 
  {src:'/assets/Friend.png'}]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onClick(imageNameObject) {
    this.imageSrc = imageNameObject.src;
    this.messageText = imageNameObject.name;}

};
```

As you see in the screen its showing 0 1 2 and i am tying to find a way to provide description rather than sequential number [Screenshot of the app/screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBLv1.png)

Comment: You print {{i}} and `i` get index. so you have `imageButtons` 3 length of array. so basically  output is 0,1,2. and also you missing `name` in `imageButtons` array

Answer (score 0):

In Html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="false">
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="search"> </ion-icon>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" ios="ellipsis-horizontal" md="ellipsis-vertical"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Pics</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <button *ngFor="let imageButton of imageButtons; let i = index" (click)="onClick(imageButton)"
    class="button">{{i}}</button>
  <img src="{{imageSrc || '/assets/test1.png'}}" (click)="addEvent();" />
  <h1>78%</h1>
</ion-content>
```

In ts

```
imageButtons = [{src:'/assets/Profile.png',name:'Profile' } , 
  {src:'/assets/Group.png',name:'Group'}, 
  {src:'/assets/Friend.png',name:'Friend'}]

onClick(imageNameObject) {
    this.imageSrc = imageNameObject.src;
    this.messageText = imageNameObject.name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ravi for providing your input. If you could please provide me guidance on how to change i to label name. I tired but either i am getting all three pics at once or only one pic.